# Using VPS to give Public IP to on home network

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding, wireguard

As my provider does not give me a public IPv4 Address, I am using a VPS combined with a Wireguard tunnel to make my homeserver reachable from the Internet (via Ipv4 and Ipv6).

On my homeserver, the traffic arrives first on a reverse proxy (Traefik). Currently, I am using rinetd to forward the incoming traffic of port 80/443 on the VPS to the Wireguard IP-Address of my Homeserver (10.10.0.2).
This works but has the problem that the source IP of the packets is always the wireguard IP of my VPS (10.10.0.1). This is a known limitation of rinetd (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/rinetd.8.html).

Plan:
Internet <-> (ens192) VPS (wg1) <-> (wg1) homeserver

Solution:

For anyone having this problem at a later point, here is the solution.

Iptables config on the VPS:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.10.0.2 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.10.0.2 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d [VPS public IP] -i ens192 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.0.2:80
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d [VPS public IP] -i ens192 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.0.2:443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j SNAT --to-source [VPS public IP]

ip6tables -I FORWARD -d fdb0:926d:918e::2 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I FORWARD -s fdb0:926d:918e::2 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d [VPS public IP] -i ens192 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination [fdb0:926d:918e::2]:80
ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d [VPS public IP] -i ens192 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination [fdb0:926d:918e::2]:443
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j SNAT --to-source [VPS public IP]
```

On the homeserver:
Configure routing:

```
ip -4 route add default dev wg1 table 4242
ip -6 route add default dev wg1 table 4242

ip -4 rule add pref 500 from 10.10.0.2 lookup 4242
ip -6 rule add pref 500 from fdb0:926d:918e::2 lookup 4242
```

and also configure the wireguard allowedIPs to allow all IPs, except the local (home) network and the public IPv4 and IPv6 of my VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Following this, I was able to make my homeserver availible using iptables, but the source IP was still only 10.10.0.1.

Because you added an `SNAT` rule to force the source IP, I would assume. The tutorial tells you to apply SNAT so that the homeserver would be tricked into correctly replying via the same WireGuard tunnel, instead of sending its replies to WAN IPs directly towards its regular default route. (Without it, clients would attempt to talk to your VPS IP but receive replies from your ISP public IP.)

Remove the SNAT rule from iptables of the VPS, then set up *policy routing* on the homeserver as an alternative, as documented in a few past threads. Use either `ip rule` or systemd-networkd's `[RoutingPolicyRule]` to ensure that if the replies are coming *from* the homeserver's WireGuard IP, they will be routed via WireGuard as well. (It might be useful to specify wg-quick's `Table=` option here, then you could create a rule that just references the table that wg-quick creates.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I found and applied what you have said, I am not sure if I did it correctly though. I updated my original post if you want to have a look.

Comment: Your remaining DNAT (port forwarding) rules seem to be missing any `-d <ip>` or `-i <iface>` check, so they accidentally catch _outgoing_ HTTP connections as well, not just incoming ones. Limit them to only packets sent to the VPS's public IP, and/or arriving via the VPS's eth0 (ens192) interface.

Comment: (As for the "FORWARD" rules, I _think_ those look okay, but I'd recommend using the typical `--ctstate ESTABLISHED` to permit all reply packets without the need for an explicit --sport rule for each port – and would probably try collapsing the individual --dport rules into a single `--ctstate DNAT` to automagically permit all packets that have gone through a DNAT rule.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't quite understand which rule to modify how yet.
The ```iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d <VPSpublicip> -i ens192 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.0.2:80``` rule should be like this I guess, and the 
dport rules should be replaced by a single ```iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.10.0.2 -p tcp --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT``` and for the sport: ```iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.10.0.2 -p tcp --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT```

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment, but I forgot the -m conntrack

Comment: Right now my problem is that my server looses internet access while connected to wireguard.

Comment: Do you still have an SNAT rule for _outgoing_ traffic (from the VPS wg1 to ens192)? You need to keep that one, for IPv4 at least (and for v6 too if you are using the 'fd' local addresses).

Comment: Thank you very much, after adding those again I have internet access again (working on IPv4 and IPv6), though I still cannot access my website via IPv6. Just to make sure: The IPv6 iptables rules are the same as the ipv4 ones just with different IP addresses, right?

Comment: For now, yes. Though for IPv6, most people would recommend not doing SNAT at all and instead directly using global addresses for the hosts (avoiding the need to DNAT/portforward as well), but if you *have* to do NAT, then it works the same as in IPv4. (Also, I am not 100% sure about the syntax of `--to-dest`, typically IPv6 uses `[addr]:port` with the brackets to separate the port number, but check `man iptables-extensions`.)

Comment: To make sure though, does your VPS itself have IPv6 connectivity first?

Comment: Yes, I can e.g. curl -6 ifconfig.co to see the correct public IP. I just fired up a simple nginx container on the homeserver and from the VPS I can curl both the wireguard IPv4 and IPv6 of the homeserver to see the nginx welcome page. If I try from outside the VPS though, it works via IPv4, but IPv6 it doesn't get further than "trying [IPv6]...". Is there anything I can do to diagnose?

Comment: Yes, if the system is supposed to forward packets, use a packet capture tool to _take a look_ at the packets – verify whether they are being received on the input interface (`tcpdump -n -i wg1 "ip6"`), verify whether they're being sent out on the output interface (`-i eth0`) – and whether they're being sent out with their source IP correctly 'SNAT'ed/'MASQUERADE'd, if you use that – and whether any replies arrive back on that interface from the server, and finally whether those replies (if any) are being sent out via wg1 towards the client.

Comment: Using packet capture on the VPS and homeserver the traffic has nothing obsivous wrong to me, but I do believe I found the culprit looking at my PCs traffic after sending the curl request. First my PC sends a TCP packet to the public IPv6 of the VPS, but recieves the reply from the wireguard IPv6 of the homeserver, so my ip6tables rules aren't masking the origin correctly as it seems.

Comment: That sounds like the usual problem with "NAT hairpin" / "NAT loopback" that people often have with port-forwarding on their home routers. In short, you can't have the client and the server on the same network, unless you additionally SNAT the source which is a bit ugly, and which is something you specifically wanted to avoid in your original post. (Well, you _can_ limit the SNAT rule to only take effect in "loopback" scenarios but not in other cases, but it's still ugly in principle.) Since this is IPv6, my suggestion is still to avoid NAT for it and to get a public address range for wg1.

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I changed my post now if you want to have a look, got it working with that config. My problem was I misunderstood the SNAT. Once I looked at the packets on my pc I realized the source IP was being masked wrong. After fixing that and configuring docker I can now see both the correct IPv4 and IPv6 of the client.